# no se despliega boton en django

Tags: html, python, bootstrap, django

tengo una aplicaion en django donde intento poner un boton desplegable, al momento de cliquear en el este no realiza nada, alguien que me pueda orientar
[image: vista de la interfaz]

este el codigo del html

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ user}} <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Verifica que versión de bootstrap estás usando. Si es 5 o superior cambia `data-toggle=`  por `data-bs-toggle=`, pues es uno de los cambios con la versiones precedentes.  Todos los atributos `data-` han pasado a ser `data-bs-` en la versión 5 o superior a dia de hoy

Comment: ahhh ya entiendo muchas gracias